New-AzSynapseRoleAssignment gives the error The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (xx.dev.azuresynapse.net:443
When I run the command to grant synapse admin rights on an object ID in the fashion below.
$ws = Get-AzSynapseWorkspace -Name <workspace_name>
$ws | New-AzSynapseRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Synapse Administrator" -ObjectId "xxx"

I get the error below.
   New-AzSynapseRoleAssignment: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in 
    ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (xx.dev.azuresynapse.net:443)) 
(The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (xx.net:443)) (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. 

(xx.dev.azuresynapse.net:443)) (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (xx.dev.azuresynapse.net:443))

Unsure what could be causing it, the first command works, so I couldn't really say its network related.

The error message "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found" can occur when the specified object ID does not exist or cannot be found. Try checking your network connection and verifying that the object ID exists.

The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found (xx.dev.azuresynapse.net:443).

According to this MS document,

the socket error points to some sort of DNS or A Record issue. Check the virtual tags and services service-tags-overview.

After resolving the DNS issue, you may be able to assign a role to the user or service principal successfully, as shown below:
$ws = Get-AzSynapseWorkspace -Name <workspaceName>
$ws | New-AzSynapseRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Synapse Administrator" -ObjectId "****"



@learner Check if above provided solution works for you?
